# Is "are you done for" similar to "are you ready for"?

Tags: meaning, past-participles

I heard this question: "Are you done for sushi?". I guess the guy who asked this question meant "Are you ready to eat sushi?".

Is it right or did I mishear the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misheard the quote.  Your friend probably asked:

> *Are you down for sushi?*

*Down for* is used slangily, and is (perhaps ironically) roughly equivalent to *up for*.

So, he was basically asking, "Do you wanna have some sushi?"

Answer (score 2):

**Done for:** doomed to death or extinction (though not *literally*, as shown in the following example)

> How dare you do that! Now you are **done for**.

**Done** is also used colloquially as,

> I am **done**. (I have *finished*.)
>
> Are you **done**? (Have you *finished*? or Are you *ready*?)
>
> Are you **done** for the party? (Are you *ready* for the party?)
>
> Are you **done** for swimming? (Have you *completed* whatever task were doing and are *ready* for swimming?)

So, technically, **"are you done for sushi?"** is incorrect. Though, its use in informal conversations is alright.

Comment: I don't understand the "technically incorrect" part. What does "technically" even mean?

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 I am sure you will find your answer [here](http://goo.gl/3YNLz)

Comment: Is "Are you done for the party?" correct? Because seems similar to "Are you done for sushi?"

Comment: @DarionBadlydone Yes, it's correct. You can see that I have included it in the list above.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with rudra, 'are you done for' implies a note of doom or death, usually used in a jocular fashion.  My mother was very found of this expression and nearly always used it in a jocular manner.

I could imagine someone jovially using it in the context of sushi to indicate the risk taken after eating sushi, especially if someone thinks of the blowfish.